# To remap Ctrl-c to Ctrl-q is not working in input mode

Tags: vim

When I try to call ReplaceIt(), I can type ctrl-c to quit input.

```
function! ReplaceIt()
    call inputsave()
    let replacement = input('Enter replacement:')
    call inputrestore()
    execute '%s//'.replacement.'/g'
endfunction
```

But I have already map Ctrl-c to <Esc><Esc>, I need to remap other key to Ctrl-c before that.

I try to set `map <C-q> <C-c>`.
This seting is no use while typing.

Is there any better way to remap key or to quit input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mode while in `input()` is *command-line mode* (i.e. `:cmap`). Even an unmapped `<C-C>` will cause `input()` to return the empty string, so you should probably check for that (`if empty(replacement)`) and abort your function.

However, I would solve this without explicit `input()` (which is not efficient and has problems when recalled in a macro):

```
:nnoremap <Leader>r :%s///g<Left><Left>
```

Comment: With cmap I think I can map `<c-q>` to input md5(quit), and let vim detect that to do nothing.
`:nnoremap <Leader>r :%s///g<Left><Left>` is nice solution.
I just want to let it to be simple with input.